# Add or edit data if already exist in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to add or edit data depending if its already stored in the database. As you can see below im checking if user already exist with `getuserid($id)` loading the corresponding view but the problem is when i trigger `add_user()` or `edit_user()` as none of these methods are redirecting back as it should be. Any suggestions? This is the complete code http://pastebin.com/2G7D8ie4

```
 public function getuserid($id = NULL){

    if(!$id)
    {
        show_404();            
    }

    $query = $this->Users_model->getuserid($id);

    if($query == false){

            $data = array('title'=>'Admin ::LxFPanamá::',
                            'content'=>'users/add_users_view',
                            'id'=>$id);
        }else{

            $data = array('title'=>'Admin ::LxFPanamá::',
                            'content'=>'users/edit_users_view',
                            'id'=> $query->id,
                            'staff_id'=> $query->staff_id,
                            'login'=> $query->login,
                            'password'=> $query->password   
                            );
        }

        $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->config->item('theme_front').'.php', $data);

}
```

Model

```
  public function getuserid($id){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('staff_id' => $id));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){

        return $query->row();

    }else{

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post getuserid model function ?

Comment: I have edited the posted code

Answer (score 0):

can you try making your `model`

```
public function getuserid($id){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('staff_id' => $id));
        $result=array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $rows){
            $result[]=$rows;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

and `controller`

```
    if(count($query)>0){
    $data = array('title'=>'Admin ::LxFPanamá::',
                  'content'=>'users/edit_users_view',
                  'id'=> $query->id,
                  'staff_id'=> $query->staff_id,
                  'login'=> $query->login,
                  'password'=> $query->password
                  );
}
else
{
    $data = array('title'=>'Admin ::LxFPanamá::',
                  'content'=>'users/add_users_view',
                  'id'=>$id
                  );
}
```